# Routing issue on Single Page Application on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, single-page-application

Using Flask as the web server, and Angular as my SPA in a /static directory. I implemented a catch-all end point on my Flask app to try solve an issue where users were being given a `404` when they refresh a page, but it did not solve the issue. Does anyone know how to fix this?

The catch-all looks like:

```
@application.route('/', defaults={'path': ''}) 
@application.route('/static/<path:path>') 
def main(path): 
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I also implemented a redirect if a 404 is thrown, but this hasn't helped either:

```
@application.errorhandler(Exception)
@cross_origin()
def main_404(*args, **kwargs):
    logger.info("Routing passed to web application...") 
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: If you route to `/static/`, you haven't routed to `/static/<path:path>`. ;That could be a problem with the catch all handler.

Comment: The issue seems to be due to the /static directory. If I type in elasticbeanstalkurl.com/foobar/foo my redirect for 404s works perfectly. But when a user is on a page and they hit refresh, with the url being elasticbeanstalkurl.com/static/foo they get a 404. This is because beanstalk is trying to find a file called /foo in the /static directory (kinda like how /static/index.html does take them to the application). Any idea how I could stop this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using error handlers if you want to catch errors:

```py
@application.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    app.logger.error('Page not found: %s', (request.path))
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

Comment: What I hoped would work was exactly that errorHandler, except "return render_template('index.html')", but no luck - bizarrely the users are still given a 404. I even tried return just a basic string to test the function but still returns a 404.

Comment: I updated the code snippet in the question to reflect this.

Comment: Does the application still call the `page_not_found` error or does the application ignore the error handler?